# compositeData of nested Custom Controls with callback

Tags: xpages

I have 2 custom controls that should be generally reusable. One is for simple formatting of a field (with lable, styles etc). One is reused in repeat for table editing. To the editing one I'm passing datasource that it should use.

Problem is that if I try to create control in the editor and put it into the the formatting one, compositeData is evaluated from context of the last one, so it can't find the data source.

Simple setup is:

Xpage

```
 <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
  xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
 <xp:this.data>
  <xp:dominoDocument var="document1"></xp:dominoDocument>
 </xp:this.data>

 <xc:middleCC>
  <xc:this.ds>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:document1;}]]>
  </xc:this.ds>
 </xc:middleCC>
</xp:view>
```

middleCC

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
 xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
  <xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{compositeData.ds.myfield}"></xp:inputText>
  <xc:lastCC>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#{compositeData.ds.myfield}"></xp:inputText>
  </xc:lastCC>
</xp:view>
```

lastCC

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
 <xp:callback />
</xp:view>
```

And I get error

Error testing property 'myfield' in bean of type null

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: How is your ds propery on middleCC defined?

Comment: As com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData . It works fine if used directly in that CC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to rearchitect your solution a little. Instead of trying to pass the datasource through the parameters, pass a string that evaluates to the datasource at the last step. so your middle would look like this:

```
<xc:lastCC BindTo="#{compositeData.dsName}.fieldName">
    <xp:inputText id="inputText2">
       <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:"#{"+compositeData.BindTo+"}"}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:inputText>
<xc:lastCC>
```

your lastCC needs a parameter `BindTo` (pick your own name) and your XPage would look like:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
  xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
 <xp:this.data>
     <xp:dominoDocument var="document1"></xp:dominoDocument>
 </xp:this.data>
 <xc:middleCC dsName="document1">
 </xc:middleCC>
</xp:view>
```

Let us know how it goes

Comment: This would work. But in same way I can just pass the datasource directly. I misunderstood how is the callback interpreted. It just evaluates everything in same was as if I copy-paste it in place of the call back.

Comment: That's correct. The callback becomes part of the control. You still might want to opt for the string version since you are more flexible with the datasource. Anything that is a valid EL will work

Answer (score 0):

As Stephan suggested, I had to pass necessary context further down to lastCC. I could also pass the datasource.

```
<xc:lastCC >
    <xc:this.ds>
        <![CDATA[#{compositeData.ds}]]>
    </xc:this.ds>
    <xp:inputText id="inputText2"
        value="#{compositeData.ds.myfield}">
    </xp:inputText>
</xc:lastCC>
```

Still more code than I would expect, but at least I can keep it reusable (as far as I remember that if I use different ds, I have to evaluate form name of parameter in LastCC and map it accordingly.